# High school equations and inequalities question

Tags: inequality

[image: having issues with second part]

I've arrived at the condition that $-2<k-m<2$, but am unsure how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you wondering how to get from $-2<k-m<2$ to $(k-m)^2 < 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+kx=mx-1\iff x^2+(k-m)x+1=0\implies \Delta=(k-m)^2-4$$

Now, notice that for no real roots, we must have $\Delta\lt 0$

**Note:** $\Delta$ denotes the discriminant.

---

Now, we know that $(k-m)^2\lt 4$ and $4\lt k\lt 8$.

Then, equivalently, by the reverse triangle inequality, $||k|-|m||\leq |k-m|\lt 4$, or equivalently, $$-4\lt |k|-|m|\lt +4\implies\begin{cases} |m|\lt |k|+4\lt 8+4=12\\ |m|\gt |k|-4\gt 4-4=0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your inequalities to get $-2+m < k < 2 +m$. What can you conclude about the possible values of $m$ given that $4 < k <8$.